# algorithm to detect ¨standable¨ places in a mesh?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, mesh, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I'm making a VR application that involves a user dynamically loading 3d models.

The user should be able to teleport to any place that resembles a floor, platform, or other kind of horizontal surface. For that, I need to find the coordinates where those planes lie - which aren't necessarily whole meshes, but perhaps a part of it (consider a single mesh of a room where the walls can't be teleported on but the floor can).

Is there a known algorithm that can be used for this use case?

Comment: you should consider the *half-edge* storage structure, or any other one that allows you to query adjacent faces efficiently, and find any contiguous areas with large enough area and sufficiently low variation in altitude

Comment: select faces with dot product of their normals with standing normal less then threshold ... then check area size ...